# Recently I found a sequence , for $n(n+1)+1$ form of multiples of 7.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I was trying to find multiples of $7$ of the form $ n^2 + n + 1 = n(n+1) + 1$.

And I found that if you start with $2$ then, observe the pattern

> $$ 2 \times 3 + 1 ,\  (2 + 3 -1)(2+3) +1, \ (2+3+2+3-1)(2+3+2+3) + 1,...$$

It is same as

> $$ 2 \times 3 + 1 , \ 4 \times 5 +1 , \ 9 \times 10 + 1,\ 18 \times 19 +1,... $$

These all satisfy the requirement.

Is this a coincidence or there is some theorem, or proof related to it? Also as matter of fact, it doesn't include all the numbers of $ n^2 + n + 1$ form.

Please tell some good method to find it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You just need to check solutions in the set of least residues modulo $7$.

Comment: Please elaborate, residues ?

Comment: Are you familiar with modular arithmetic?  The solutions to $n^2+n+1\equiv 0 \pmod 7$ are $n\equiv 2,4\pmod 7$.

Comment: $n^2+n+1$ is always an odd number. $1$ out of $7$ odd numbers is divisible by $7$.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with modular arithmetic (just a beginner), but how solutions to $n^2+n+1 \equiv 0 (\mod 7)$ are $n \equiv 2,4 (\mod 7)$ ?

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi Any n is congruent to exactly one of the elements in the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\} \operatorname{mod} 7$. You can pretty easily show that if $n\equiv 2$ or $4$ then $n^2+n+1\equiv 0\operatorname{mod} 7$. Now suppose $n$ is not $\equiv 2$ or $4$. What is it congruent to? Can you rule out these other possibilities?

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 I didn't get your question completely, but I think there could be no other possibility, because it could either of form $7k + 2$ or $7k + 4$.

Comment: I believe I am wrong... Please guide me.

Comment: Please write an *informative* title.  Yours states nothing, and will not help others find the question or its solution.

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi Let's say I want to rule out the possibility of $n=7k+5$. If $n=7k+5$, then $n\equiv 5\operatorname{mod} 7$. So $n^2+n+1\equiv 5^2+5+1 \operatorname{mod} 7$. Can you proceed from here to show that $n=7k+5$ is impossible? And then do the same for $7k+1, 7k+3, 7k+6$?

Comment: Yes, thank you .